# jQuery mobile: panel open not triggered after page navigation

Tags: php, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I am creating a mobile website using jQuery mobile (1.3).

In this site I'm using a panel for my menu, which get activated by the 'bars' button in the top left of the screen or by swiping from left to right (on desktops; click and move mouse to the right).

This all is working fine until I navigate to a different page. The new page loads using the jQuery mobile AJAX function, in the console.log my panel div is logged so I know it's there but the .panel('open') function is not triggered.

I tried making my links 2 different ways with no luck:

```
<a href="?controller=website&action=algemeenInvoer">Algemene invoer</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('?controller=website&action=algemeenInvoer', { transition:'slideup'} );">Algemene invoer, using mobile.changePage</a>
```

Since I use php I can't create a simple JSFiddle demonstrating the problem but here is a link to my dev page: *snip*

I hope someone can help me fix this problem and my .panel('open') is triggered after page navigation.

**EDIT:**
Current swipe function:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
    $('div[data-role="content"]').on("swiperight",function(){
        console.log($('#menu'));

        //open panel after swiped x px.
        $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 80;
        $('#menu').panel("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: It's working normally. What's the problem exactly and how do you open it? Tested on iPad and iPhone.

Comment: when entering the site it's working fine. Try to navigate to a different page you'll see that when the page is loaded the swipe action won't active the panel. pushing the bars icon on top left however is.

Comment: True, update your question with swipe function pls.

Comment: I found your problem, I will write you an answer.

Comment: @Gajotres , looking forward to you solution!

Comment: Don't bind it to pageinit as it trigger once, that's it. Just remove pageinit function and leave the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your page logic.

When new page is opened it is just another page loaded into the DOM. But when you try to open a panel inside a second page it will try to open a first page panel because they have the same.

I have tested this on your page and it is working:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#menu').panel("open");
```

## Proof

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

        <title>Logboek</title>

        <!-- Springboard icon (retina) -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />

        <!-- iPhone 4(S) startup image -->
        <link href="images/splash-screen-640x920.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-height: 480px)"/>
        <!-- iPhone 5 startup image -->
        <link href="images/splash-screen-640x1096.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-height: 568px)"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://logboek.zavee.nl/public/css/theme/TEAM-WJM.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageinit',function(){
                $('div[data-role="content"]').on("swiperight",function(){
                    console.log('swipe');
                    $.mobile.activePage.find('#menu').panel("open");
                });
            });                     
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="index">
            <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-theme="d">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d">
                    <li><a href="second.html">Algemene invoer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('?controller=website&action=algemeenInvoer', { transition:'slideup'} );">Algemene invoer, using mobile.changePage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?controller=website&action=trainingInvoer">Training invoeren</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('?controller=website&action=trainingInvoer', { transition:'slideup'} );">Training invoeren, , using mobile.changePage</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">Overzicht bekijken</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                <a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true"></a>
                <h1>Trainingslogboek</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" id="content">
<form method="post" action="text.php">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="datum">Datum:</label>
        <input type="date" name="datum" id="datum" />
    </div>  

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="gewicht">Gewicht in kg:</label>
        <input type="number" name="gewicht" id="gewicht" data-clear-btn="true" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">    
        <label for="op">Ochtendpols:</label>
        <input type="number" name="op" id="op" data-clear-btn="true" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Slaap:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1a" value="on" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1a">1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1b" value="off" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1b">2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1c" checked="checked" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1c">3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1d" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1d">4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1e" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1e">5</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>  

    <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />  
</form>         </div> <!-- /content -->
        </div> <!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

#### second.html

```
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="second">
            <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-theme="d">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d">
                    <li><a href="?controller=website&action=algemeenInvoer">Algemene invoer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('?controller=website&action=algemeenInvoer', { transition:'slideup'} );">Algemene invoer, using mobile.changePage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?controller=website&action=trainingInvoer">Training invoeren</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('?controller=website&action=trainingInvoer', { transition:'slideup'} );">Training invoeren, , using mobile.changePage</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">Overzicht bekijken</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                <a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true"></a>
                <h1>Trainingslogboek</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" id="content">
<form>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="datum">Datum:</label>
        <input type="date" name="datum" id="datum" />
    </div>  

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">  
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend></legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1a" data-mini="true" value="on" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1a">1<sup>e</sup></label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1b" data-mini="true" value="off" disabled="disabled" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1b">2<sup>e</sup></label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1c" data-mini="true" value="other" disabled="disabled" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1c">3<sup>e</sup></label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1d" data-mini="true" value="other" disabled="disabled" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-1d" style="padding-bottom:2px;">training van vandaag.</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>   

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>EMI score:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2d" checked="checked" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2d">4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2e" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2e">5</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend></legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">6</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">7</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">8</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2d" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2d">9</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2e" value="other" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2e">10</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Blessure:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-3" id="radio-choice-h-3a" value="on" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-3a">Ja</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-3" id="radio-choice-h-3b" value="off" />
            <label for="radio-choice-h-3b">Nee</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>         
</div> <!-- /content -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It's working perfect now and learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the code inside `pageinit`, as the last fires once only.

```
$('div[data-role="content"]').on("swiperight",function(){
 var activepage = '#' + $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
 $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 80;
 $('activepage #menu').panel("open");
});
```