# JQM - Panel - events not triggered after navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, triggers

I have the same problem that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509926/jquery-mobile-panel-open-not-triggered-after-page-navigation). But the solution doesnt work with my project.

I use ASP.NET MVC4 and JQM. I have one JS file loaded in the head section.
I have a menu like this :

```
<a href="#left-panel" id="link-menu" class="ui-panel-animate"></a>
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-display="push">
  <ul data-role="listview">
   ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

my link menu CSS class :

```
#link-menu
{
  top: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("images/icons-36-white.png"); 
}
```

It's a image, it position is absolute. So when panel is opened i have to add :

```
.Menu-decalage {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(272px,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(272px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(272px,0,0);    
}
```

In my JS file i have added :

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
  $("#left-panel").panel({
    beforeopen: function (event, ui) {
        $("#link-menu").addClass("Menu-decalage");
    },
    beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
        $("#link-menu").removeClass("Menu-decalage");
    }
});
```

It works when the first page is loaded, not after navigation.
I have understood that the code is executed on the first page, and i have tried with :

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#left-panel').panel();
```

but it doesn't work.

I have tried to change

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
```

to

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
```

but activePage is undefined.

So if someone can give me a solution : Thank you

Comment: Is your `#left-panel` inside of a JQM page?

Comment: @shanabus : Yes.
left-panel is in the menu.html and I have
`<div data-role="page" id="page" >      
                Html.RenderPartial("Menu");
...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution by adding the image in html with relative position and removing background image of the link.

thanks for your help

Comment: This answer seems to have nothing to do with the question you asked.

Comment: Exactly, but I had no more time to look for a solution and i had to fix the problem...
I don't like this solution and if I find better, I will add the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `});` in your `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow'...` section.

If that doesn't fix the problem post more of your html and that may help.

**UPDATE**

When the JS is run once (initial load), often times that means that your JS code is not part of the page.  Try moving your `pagebeforeshow` binding inside of the page you want it bound in.  So you would have:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  </div>

  <script>
  ... on pagebeforeshow method ...
  </script>

  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's just an oversight and doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have put the code in a Fiddle.
You can't run because the version of JQM is 1.1.1. 
The problem is that the panel's triggers are executed on the first load of page. 
When I do a "redirection" the Js is reloaded and triggers not executed.

Comment: Hi
I have tried to add the code inside the page but i have the same problem. It doesnt work after navigation.